# Javascript not reading HTML form input without reload

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the kite publisher api from 
https://kite.trade/docs/connect/v1/#custom-html5-buttons

it uses .js source 'https://kite.trade/publisher.js?v=1'

it includes various variables that can be passed to trade a stock, like the exchange name,quantity etc. I am trying to create a webpage where one can select whether to buy/sell a share by selecting buy/sell.

the HTML page code is :

```
    <form method="post">

<p><label>Would you like to Buy or Sell the shares?</label></p>
<p>
    <select id="transaction-type">
                 <option value="BUY">Buy</option>
                 <option value="SELL">Sell</option>
    </select>
</p>


<button id="custom-button">GO!</button>

  </form>
```

I have modified the source to pass html form input (buy/sell) to KiteConnect function in the .js file [.js source modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMl08.jpg)

the script is linked to a button through 'kite.link("#custom-button");'

I am getting the following problem :
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMdus.gif)  the page/frame needs to be reloaded for the script to read values, other wise the script is running with old values.

I tried periodically refreshing the page, that works, but is not a practical solution.

how do I fix the script to execute the value selected, without reloading the page?

if there is a better method altogether, please suggest.

Comment: To read the value of the select drop down box, please refer the following page :

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_value.asp

Comment: please see the https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMl08.jpg I have included in the question, I believe that is how I am trying to access the drop down box value, and it is being read after reload. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMdus.gif

Comment: You may use sessionStorage object to do so.

Comment: $("#transaction-type :selected").Val()